# Queue not populating after AJAX XML read in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am modifying a fullcalendar and want to include a feature that keeps track of the last 5 deleted items. It should display them in a textarea when you click a button. I have this part working, but I want to be able to read from an XML file, then store the string value in a fixed length queue, got that [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2308-creating-a-fixed-length-queue-in-javascript-using-arrays.htm).

However in the below code it will not let me push to the queue. Do I need to pass the variable to the array or how should I be handling this? Sorry if this is a basic error but I don't have too much experience in this area. Thanks!

```js
    // Create a constructor for the fixed-length queue. This is
    // really more of a FACTORY than a construtor since an
    // entirely tangential object is returned.
    function FixedQueue( size, initialValues ){
        // If there are no initial arguments, default it to
        // an empty value so we can call the constructor in
        // a uniform way.
        initialValues = (initialValues || []);
        // Create the fixed queue array value.
        var queue = Array.apply( null, initialValues );
        // Store the fixed size in the queue.
        queue.fixedSize = size;
        // Add the class methods to the queue. Some of these have
        // to override the native Array methods in order to make
        // sure the queue lenght is maintained.
        queue.push = FixedQueue.push;
        queue.splice = FixedQueue.splice;
        queue.unshift = FixedQueue.unshift;
        // Trim any initial excess from the queue.
        FixedQueue.trimTail.call( queue );
        // Return the new queue.
        return( queue );
    }
    // I trim the queue down to the appropriate size, removing
    // items from the beginning of the internal array.
    FixedQueue.trimHead = function(){
        // Check to see if any trimming needs to be performed.
        if (this.length <= this.fixedSize){
            // No trimming, return out.
            return;
        }
        // Trim whatever is beyond the fixed size.
        Array.prototype.splice.call(
            this,
            0,
            (this.length - this.fixedSize)
        );
    };
    // I trim the queue down to the appropriate size, removing
    // items from the end of the internal array.
    FixedQueue.trimTail = function(){
        // Check to see if any trimming needs to be performed.
        if (this.length <= this.fixedSize){
            // No trimming, return out.
            return;
        }
        // Trim whatever is beyond the fixed size.
        Array.prototype.splice.call(
            this,
            this.fixedSize,
            (this.length - this.fixedSize)
        );
    };
    // I synthesize wrapper methods that call the native Array
    // methods followed by a trimming method.
    FixedQueue.wrapMethod = function( methodName, trimMethod ){
        // Create a wrapper that calls the given method.
        var wrapper = function(){
            // Get the native Array method.
            var method = Array.prototype[ methodName ];
            // Call the native method first.
            var result = method.apply( this, arguments );
            // Trim the queue now that it's been augmented.
            trimMethod.call( this );
            // Return the original value.
            return( result );
        };
        // Return the wrapper method.
        return( wrapper );
    };
    // Wrap the native methods.
    FixedQueue.push = FixedQueue.wrapMethod(
        "push",
        FixedQueue.trimHead
    );
    FixedQueue.splice = FixedQueue.wrapMethod(
        "splice",
        FixedQueue.trimTail
    );
    FixedQueue.unshift = FixedQueue.wrapMethod(
        "unshift",
        FixedQueue.trimTail
    );

function populateQueue () {
    var removedEvents = FixedQueue(5, ["","","","",""]);
    var title, words = "";

    jQuery('#binBox').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: './xml/deleted.xml',
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'xml',            
        success: function(returnedXMLResponse) {
            $('item', returnedXMLResponse).each(function() {
                title = $('fullnote', this).text();
                words += title + "\n";
                jQuery('#bin').val(words);
                removedEvents.push(words); // this does not work
            })
        }  
    });  
}
```

Comment: Does the `FixedQueue()` function return an array? If not, that's your issue. Could you please add the code of `FixedQueue()` to the question, and also check the console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: It is a constructor, it does return the queue. I have edited my question to include all of the Fixed Queue code. I don't get any errors in the console.

Comment: Ok, what do you see in the console if you add the following line after the `push()` call: `console.log(removedEvents);`

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it is populating the removedEvents queue when I put console.log on the following line. However when I put console.log after the success function is displays as empty. Any idea how I could make it keep the content?

Comment: You can't. The AJAX call is asynchronous. This means that code execution continues on past the `$.ajax` call while the request is sent. Therefore if you try and work with the `removedEvents` array outside of the `success` block it will be undefined/empty. You need to place all code that relies on the `removedEvents` within the `success` block, or call it from there.

Comment: Ah I see, OK I may need a different method of reading the XML file then. Thanks, I appreciate your help on this

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Be aware though that what you have now is the best method, as you want the read to be done asynchronously. If you don't then the browser will appear to the user as though it has locked/crashed while the XML is being retrieved.

Comment: Ok I see your point. I don't actually need to add to the queue in this function but I will in the next function I write. Just need to read the XML file, populate the fixed length queue, push the latest entry on to it, then write to XML again. So as long as I do all from the success block it should work.